# Enumeration to find Nth prime with Python

Tags: python, loops, primes, enumeration

I have decided it is about time that i should start learning to code. I have some knowledge of HTML and CSS but i want to be able to develop for iOS. I am aware i have a long way to go, but i aim to get there step by step.

I'm working through the MIT Python course on iTunes U and I am stuck on the homework. I understand the concept of enumeration and testing every possible outcome to find the primes, however what i have tried so far has failed me. My closest attempt is the following.

```
# counting confirmed primes. For loop should do remainder tests on
# all testNumbers, unless caught by the if statements that rule out
# multiples of 2,3,5,7 to speed things up. divisor increments by one
# on those numbers that do not get pulled by qualifying if statements

testNumber = 2
confirmedPrime = 0

while (confirmedPrime < 1001):
        for divisor in range(1, testNumber+1):
                if (testNumber/2)*2== testNumber:
                        testNumber += 1
                elif (testNumber/3)*3 == testNumber:
                        testNumber += 1
                elif (testNumber/5)*5 == testNumber:
                        testNumber += 1
                elif (testNumber/7)*7 == testNumber:
                        testNumber += 1
                elif(testNumber%divisor == 0):
                        testNumber += 1
        confirmedPrime +=1
print testNumber
```

This however doesn't return the "7919" i am expecting but. It returns "7507" So somewhere there are some composites slipping through the net.

I have hunted through this site and not managed to solve it so I thought I would ask.

Comment: If you want to develop for iOS, learn Objective-C.Write in it. I am not saying you should not learn python.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing.  Python won't send you in the direction of iOS

Comment: i was learning objective-c a bit, but i felt somewhat out of my depth, and all of the more basic free courses i could find were based on scripting languages. I see this a way to tune my brain to think through a program like a programmer.

Comment: Do not try to do any speedups in the beginning (your speedups are slowdowns, and one reason for the bug), and write your algorithm on the paper in plain English first, and only then code it in Python.

Comment: I have tried this multiple different ways, and each of them started on paper. Note taken on the optimisations though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few bits are off here, so let's go step by step.

You start by setting initial values, which is perfectly reasonable.

```
testNumber=2
confirmedPrime = 0
```

Then you go into a while loop, continuing until the value of the variable `confirmedPrime` is has reached (i.e. is equal to or bigger than) 1001. I suppose your task is to find the 1000th prime, but doing it like this you're actually finding the 1001st, because the `while` loop continues until `confirmedPrime` has the value of 1001. Change it to

```
while(confirmedPrime < 1000):
```

You immediately go into another loop, and here comes the first problem, even though it isn't what's giving you the wrong answer.

```
    for divisor in range(1, testNumber+1)
        if (testNumber/2)*2 == testNumber:
            ...
```

Doing the tests for multipliers of 2, 3, 5 and 7 *inside* the `for` loop doesn't make any sense, as you only have to to this once for each value of `testNumber`. So that part of the testing should be moved out of the for loop.

```
    if (testNumber/2)*2 = testNumber: # Why not use modulo here too for consistency?
        testNumber += 1
    elif ...
        ...
    else:
        for divisor in range(...):
```

The next part is testing for other, larger divisors. You are testing divisors in the range 1 to `testNumber+1`. I'm not sure why you're doing this, but it's not a good idea, as your modulo test will always return zero when you come to the second last iteration, testing `testNumber%testNumber`. So you should change it to `testNumber-1`, in fact you can stop when you have reached the square root of `testNumber`, but I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

Now comes the biggest problem:
After the `for` loop is finished, you increment `confirmedPrimes` by 1 without actually checking if you found a prime or not. So, incrementing `confirmedPrimes` should only happen if none of the first tests were true *and* none of the "divisor tests" turned out to be true.

Rewritten using underscores instead of mixedCase (which is bad python mojo), consistent spacing etc:

```
import math

test_number = 7       # Already know up to 7
confirmed_primes = 4  # Already know about 2, 3, 5 and 7

while confirmed_primes < 1000:
    test_number += 1

    if test_number % 2 and test_number % 3 and test_number % 5 and test_number % 7:
        is_prime = True

        for divisor in range(11, int(math.sqrt(test_number))+1):
            if test_number % divisor == 0:
                is_prime = False

        if is_prime:
            confirmed_primes += 1

print test_number
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I assumed that the for loop would break at the point where the divisor became == testNumber (using mixedCase here in reference to my own work) at which point i would be left with a prime so i would increment the prime count then. I didnt realise i could execute the check for multiples of 2,3,4,5,7 etc on the same line, new syntax to play with there. I did play with the math.sqrt a few times but i went back to take out all extra complexities as i was failing. The testNumber+1 was merely a typo left over from that test. Thankyou that has helped me a huge amount

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand exactly how your algorithm is supposed to find a prime number.

A number is said to be prime if it's only divisible by 1 or himself.

Another definition is that a number is said to be prime if it's not divisible by any prime number smaller than it.

This can be the base of your algorithm, speeding up the process by a lot.

```
def nth_prime(n):
    prime_list = []
    current = 2
    count = 0
    while(count < n):
        is_prime = True
        for prime in prime_list:
            if current % prime == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            prime_list.append(current)
            count += 1
        current += 1
    return current - 1

print nth_prime(1000) # => 7919
```

Comment: If i am checking whether each number cleanly divides by an incremental divisor. Surely that would check whether the number is "divisible by  1 or himself". Discarding those that divide cleanly at any point, and counting those that do not after the incremental divisor has matched the test number. Is my logic in that messed up?

Comment: The original algorithm is called the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes. Any number not divisible by 2,3,5, or 7 is a prime number (with the exception of the numbers 2,3,5, and 7, which are also prime numbers). It is a *fast* method.